# SpeechSynthesizer.speakTextAsync callback when it's finished

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm facing the issue with Azure `speakTextAsync` callback issue it's `azure` `SpeechSDK` support?

Here is the sample link -> [You can check](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/node/text-to-speech)

Code

```
try
{
    var player = new SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();
    var audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);
    var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("KEY", "REGION");
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = getCurrentLanguageCode();
    synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
        inputText,
        function (result) {
            console.log(result)
            if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
                //some callback
            }
            synthesizer.close();
        },
        function (err) {                      
            synthesizer.close();                       
        })

    synthesizer.synthesisCompleted = function (s, e) {
        console.log(s)
        console.log(e)
        //some callback
    };
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

In this, I've tried two ways

1. `SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted`
2. `synthesizer.synthesisCompleted`

But both are called when the `speakTextAsync` method call.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution

Just need to add the code

Player code

```
player.onAudioEnd = function () {
 console.log('speakTextAsync finished');
}
```

Full speak code

```
synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
inputText,
function (result) { 
    synthesizer.close();
    player.onAudioEnd = function () {
        console.log('speakTextAsync finished');
    }
},
function (err) {                      
    synthesizer.close();                       
})
```